# Get text offset from click event via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I have searched all over trying to figure out how to do the following and have yet to find a solution:

I need to get the text offset for a given HTML element from a click event. This means that if I have the following HTML

```
<p>This is a really cool paragraph</p>
```

and a user clicks on the first 'a' in the sentence, the text offset would be 8 seeing as the first 'a' is at index 8 if we take the 'T' in 'This' as index 0.

I need this information so that I may programmatically create a text selection based on where a user clicks. As of right now I can track which HTML elements are clicked on and thus I can create this sort of activity at a HTML-element level granularity, but I'd like to have finer control than that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from your comment in another answer:

> I'm currently trying to simulate human behavior via Javascript which
>   is turning out to be a bit more difficult than I anticipated (most
>   likely by design).

What you want is Selenium, for web browser automation:  http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Yeah that's pretty darn close to exactly what I need. I wonder now how difficult / time-consuming this is to learn; we're sort of on a deadline here!

Comment: @MoarCodePlz I had a lot of difficulty integrating it with our CI system (Jenkins), but for quick standalone scripts, it works very well.  There's even a Firefox addon that allows you to basically hit "record" and "play" and export the result to various languages.  It doesn't catch everything, though, so the result usually needs some cleanup.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz Oh, right: The various ways it can click on the page are based on CSS selectors, the text of a link, and (X,Y) coordinates inside a CSS-selected element.  So no character-level clicking.

Answer (score 2):

Using Prototype:

```
<p id='mytext'>This is a really cool paragraph</p>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var characters = $('mytext').textContent;
   var newchars = '';
   for(I = 0;I < chars.length;I++) {
      newchars += '<span id="char_' + I + '">' + chars[I] + '</span>';
   }
   $('mytext').textContent = newchars;
   Event.observe($('mytext'), 'click', function(e) {
      var spanID = (e.findElement('span')).getAttribute('id')
      var index = spanID.split('_')[1]; // Ta-daaa!
   });
</script>
```

Please don't do this for large blocks of text (or, preferably, at all).  It creates a DOM node for every character, and can slow the browser down...

Comment: Funnily enough this is what I am doing for another project I'm working on. Like you said though, large documents would suffer pretty horrendously from this being done at a character granularity.

Comment: Depending on the level of fidelity needed, this approach could be made more reasonable by, eg, wrapping every N characters in a span, or wrapping every sentence in a span... in the latter case, I'd do the wrapping at or before render time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything built in for that. Any solution will be a hack and unreliable.

What you *can* do is use the [selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsISelection) to get a user selection on a page, which sounds like you can do.

Comment: Yes I'm starting to come to the same conclusion. Unfortunately I'm not developing this for use in public-facing websites and things of that sort; it is for an experiment. I'm currently trying to simulate human behavior via Javascript which is turning out to be a bit more difficult than I anticipated (most likely by design).

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there as a possible hack/solution.

You could try using the mouse offsetX and offsetY when a click occurs and simulate a double click `dblclick` in that location, effectively selecting the text and then using the selection API to get the word they clicked. Wouldn't work to the letter, but might work to the word.

Answer (score 1):

Append each letter inside a span tag and onClick event just extract the letter inside the span tag and may be keep reference with some attributes in the span tag for tracking the index of the position for each of the element.But this approach would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.getSelection()` ...I'm not sure if it works in all browsers, but at least Chrome seems to create a Selection object with the offset you need.

Comment: Except when there is already a selection and the click occurs within it: in that case it returns the old selection. And if we wait with setTimeout, there is no selection left...

Comment: I guess that might work if we intercept double clicks and drags and use a fake selection. They seem to use fake selections in [ace](http://ace.ajax.org), and apparently they have found a way to find the character position for a given click.